# This application requires one of the following version of the .Net framework

Tags: c#, .net, azure

We use a pipeline in Azure devops to build our software, and an on premises agent to actually make the build.

If I install the build on an testmachine and run the application, an error message pops up that says:
This application requires one of the following version of the .Net framework: .NetFramework,Version=v4.8

The build machine only has .Net Framework 4.6.1 installed, and the app.config says

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I've checked, with JetBrains DotPeek, that the runtime of the executable and all the supporting assembly's is 4.6.1.
I can see no reference in our solution to the .Net Framework 4.8, so i wonder why the message is shown. Is there a way to find out why this message is shown, what the trigger is?

The message is only shown when Azure Devops does the build. When I build on my local development machine, the message is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried deploying .Net Framework 4.6.1 Application with Azure Devops, Worked fine for me.

Please check your **packages.config** file in your Application.

Check the Framework and change it accordingly.

You can remove or fix project dependencies in **.csproj** file.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, there was indeed a reference to "net48" in the package.config. Changing this to "net461" solved the issue.